Google Login Inside Telegram Mini apps
I am trying to implement Google login using @react-oauth/google package in Telegram's Mini App. The process is as follows:-

user clicks on a button inside miniapp
Google login opens in a window and user login with google account
I receive an auth code and send that code to backend to retrieve refresh and access tokens.

The problem I am facing is the google login is opening in some of the devices but in most of the devices nothing happens after a button click in step 1.
Google login function
// this login function is called on button click

  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: handleOnSuccessGoogleLogin,
    flow: "auth-code",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
  });


  const handleOnSuccessGoogleLogin = async (codeResponse: CodeResponse) => {
    const { code } = codeResponse;
    try {
      const { data } = await fetchAuthTokens({ code });

      const { accessToken, refreshToken } = data;

      dispatch(setAccessToken(accessToken));

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

